# Word within a Nested list python

Tags: python

I have a nested list. I need to check whether a particular string is in an element on the list - How do I do it? I am checking if "boy" is in list[0]

```
list = [["I am a boy"],["I am a girl"]]
print (list[0])
if "boy" in list[0]:
    print ("You got it")
```

Comment: You need to check if 'boy' is in "I am a boy" and "I am a girl"? The question is somewhat vague

Comment: OT: do not override `list` - this will lead to `TypeError: 'list' object is not callable` whenever you want to do things like `list(range(1,10))` afterwards.

Answer (score 3):

By referring to `list[0]`, you're referring to the *sublist* (`["I am a boy"]`) and not the string (`"I am a boy"`). To check if the substring is within the string that is within the first sublist of `list`, you must refer to the string and not the list when you perform a member check.

It is also better practice to avoid using the built-in function `list()` as a name to your variable.

```
alist = [["I am a boy"], ["I am a girl"]]
print(alist[0])    # ["I am a boy"]
if "boy" in alist[0][0]:    # Refers to the string and not the sublist
    print("You got it")
```

Hope this helped!

Comment: Thank you. That helps!
What if I want to check the entire alist for the "boy" not just the sublist[0]? Please advise.

Comment: @Chrysna Refer to Andrii Glukhyi's solution below if you want to perform the check on all the sublists.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to compare all the strings within the nested list (assuming that the sublists only have a depth of 1), you can do a nested `for` loop.

```
list = [["I am a boy"], ["I am a girl"]] 
for sub_list in list:
    for string in sub_list:
        if 'boy' in string:
            print("You got it")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a loop to check each element in your list

```
list = [["I am a boy"],["I am a girl"]]
for each in list:
    if 'girl' in each[0]:
        print("You got it")
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will give you a list of the indexes of all sublists containing "boy". I changed the name to `alist`, as **list** is a reserved word.

```
indexes = [count for count,item in enumerate(alist) if 'boy' in item[0]]
print(indexes)
```

Comment: I'm going to flag this as not an answer as it does not attempt to answer the question posed by OP.